# Regex for name in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I know this question has been asked a lot but I need a RegEx for a name validator.

The only requirements are letters are okay, No numbers, and no special characters other than 2 and the spaces cannot be at the beginning or end, the "-" and "`" are allowed also. Everything else would be invalid.

All the other answers seem to ask for a lot more and seem to get too complicated.

Currently I am using

```
/^([^\d\W]|[-])*$/
```

But this fails with the space

Sample data:

Pass:

```
Susan Johnson,
Stephanie Le'Sean,
John Pierre'-Frank
```

Fail:

```
Ricky2Good,
Jean,stewie,
Mike@dude,
Jim.  McNeil
```

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need more data. Provide sample names and your expected output. Without that we're forced to try to interpret your example and build sample data based on that, wasting our time and increasing the chance of answers that don't meet your needs.

Comment: @thetinman sorry about that no disrespect intended

Comment: Do you mean `'` instead of `\``? That's also a very [naive approach to understanding names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) as not only are accents common, but other characters are allowed as well. People with names like [FM-2030](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FM-2030) do exist.

Comment: I see you've changed the requirement to at most two spaces, rather than one. You should not change the substance of the question after an answer is posted (as it can make answers incorrect or non-sensical, possibly down-voted as a result). OK this time, we'll fix our answers, but you need to be clearer about the requirement. Can the string begin or end with one or two spaces? If there are two spaces, must they be adjacent to each other? Please clarify by editing.

Comment: Sorry, but I changed the requirement in a comment and it was suggested that I changed it in the question so I did. Not trying to piss everyone off just trying to get an answer I will edit the question so that the space cannot come before or after. Again sorry for the poor etiquette

Comment: You said (backtick) "\`" is permitted, but your examples permit single quotes! Those are different characters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've assumed that for a string to be valid, it may contain only uppercase and lowercase letters, apostrophes, dashes and at most two spaces, provided the spaces are not at the beginning or end of the string.

```
STR= "-a-z'"

r = /
    \A           # match beginning of string
    (?:          # begin non-capture group
      [#{STR}]+  # match 1+ letters, "-" or "'"
      |          # or
      [#{STR}]+\s[#{STR}]*\s?[#{STR}]+
                 # match 1+ letters, "-" or "'", space, 0+ letters, "-" or "'",
                 # optional space, 1+ letters, "-" or "'"
    )            # end non-capture group
    \z           # match end of string
    /ix          # case-indifferent and free-spacing regex definition modes
      #=> /
          \A           # match beginning of string
          (?:          # begin non-capture group
            [-a-z']+   # match 1+ letters, "-" or "'"
            |          # or
            [-a-z']+\s[-a-z']*\s?[-a-z']+
                       # match 1+ letters, "-" or "'", space, 0+ letters, "-" or "'",
                       # optional space, 1+ letters, "-" or "'"
          )            # end non-capture group
          \z           # match end of string
          /ix
```

If I did not use free-spacing mode to define the regex it would look like this:

```
r = /\A(?:[-a-z']+|[-a-z']+\s[-a-z']*\s?[-a-z']+)\z/i 

"a B-' v"    =~ r #=> 0
"aB-'v"      =~ r #=> 0
"aB-'1v"     =~ r #=> nil
"a B-'1  v"  =~ r #=> nil
" a B-1v"    =~ r #=> nil
```

If you wish to return `true` or `false`, rather than a truthy value `0` or a falsy value `nil`,  you could write, for example:

```
("a B-' v" =~ r) ? true : false #=> true
```

or (the "trick")

```
!!("a B-' v" =~ r) #=> true
```

The latter works because it is the same as:

```
!(!("a B-' v" =~ r))
  #=> !(!(0)) => !(false) => true
```

The question asks for a regex to validate names. Using a regex may be the best, but it's not the only way. If the question is really how to validate names--using a regex or otherwise--it should be stated in a way that doesn't stipulate a particular approach. Here's one way to validate without using a regex.

```
GOOD_CHARS = ('a'..'z').to_a.join << "'-"
  #=> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'-"

def validate(str)
  return false if str.empty? || (str[0]==' ' || str[-1]==' ')
  nbr_spaces = str.count(' ')
  return false if nbr_spaces > 2 
  str.downcase.count(GOOD_CHARS) + nbr_spaces == str.size
end

validate "a B-' v"   #=> true
validate "aB-'v"     #=> true
validate "aB-`1v"    #=> false 
validate "a B-'1  v" #=> false 
validate " a B-'1v"  #=> false
```

Comment: So I am trying your solution but it doesn't seem to capture anything when I plug it into http://regexr.com/. I thank you for the explanation of each piece but it doesn't seem to capture a name when used?

Comment: I don't understand. The regex you have at the link in your comment is not the one I proposed. Have you tried running my code in IRB?

Comment: I just posted the site I used previously. I plugged in your regex ````\A(?:[#{STR}]+|[#{STR}]+\s[#{STR}]+)\z```` and it says no match. So I think it's not working

Comment: Or is it ````\A(?:[-a-z`']+|[-a-z`]\s[-a-z`']+)\z/ix```` but neither are working

Comment: I just modified the solution to permit one or two spaces (not necessarily together, if two), provided they are not at the beginning or end. You want to use my regex `r` after `STR` has been substituted out. You can see that the regex works for the five strings I considered. Try those strings at your link. I just noticed it's single quotes you wish to permit, not backticks! I'll make the adjustment.

Comment: Just got it. I plugged it into my app instead of that webpage and it worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should filter for letters, no special characters (other than one space, dashes, and backticks), and no numbers:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\-\`]++(?: [a-zA-Z\-\`]++)?$/
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for this I will try it as soon as I'm back in front of my computer however my boss thinks that it should allow two spaces. Can you change it to allow two spaces

Comment: Change the criteria in the question, not in comments. Adding additional information in comments forces people trying to help to read every comment and try to put them in order.